# angular serverless deployment using esbuild

Tags: angular, angular-cli, serverless, serverless-offline

I am attempting to utilize the application builder instead of webpack as per the instructions provided in the link - https://angular.io/guide/esbuild. However, we encountered the following error while running the application in serverless offline.

```
undefined ERROR Uncaught Exception {
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module './dist/server/server'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/lambda.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
"stack": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module './dist/server/server",
"Require stack:",
"- /var/task/lambda.js",
"- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
" at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
" at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
" at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
" at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
]
}
```

Could you please help on this

Build : npm run build:dev
Run : serverless offline